# Different status bar message per sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I use the following basic command to show a status bar message; having already assigned short cut key 'Ctrl+O' to show a user form.

```
Application.StatusBar = "<<<<< Ctrl + O to show options >>>>>"
```

I have a new worksheet that I want to link to another user form.
Is there a way to have the current status bar message only showing on one worksheet (in this instance 'ALL Data') and show another status bar message on another worksheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an addition to your answer. Rather than putting code in each sheet put he code in the "Thisworkbook" module/sheet and use something similar to below

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
If Sh.Name = "Sheet1" Then
    Application.StatusBar = "Hello World"
ElseIf Sh.Name = "Sheet2" Then
    Application.StatusBar = "Hello World123"
Else
    Application.StatusBar = False
End If
End Sub
```

Could also use below if you wanted to change sheet names

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
If Sh.Index = 1 Then
    Application.StatusBar = "Hello World"
ElseIf Sh.Index = 2 Then
    Application.StatusBar = "Hello World123"
Else
    Application.StatusBar = False
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. Not sure if it's the best solution but it works for me. I added a Private Sub Worksheet_Activate() to each worksheet. where I didn't want a message to show on the status bar I added ...

```
Application.StatusBar = False
```

... where I did want a message I added;

```
Application.StatusBar = 'your text here
```

Comment: I think that's probably the best way, SMORF.

Comment: Instead of `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()` you can use `Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)` in `ThisWorkbook` so that you don't have to add that code to every sheet.